# Display thousands position

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to display only the numbers that lie in the thousands position for a value i.e. 193000 will be displayed as 193 and so on.  How do I achieve this, maybe at the template level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide by 1000?

Comment: must have had a pretty long day...this will work well thanks.

Comment: sounds good ... but maybe use integer division so the result is not a float (ie, 193, not 193.000)

Comment: @Stephen: It's not even Monday!

Comment: @Geo: just wanted to tell you I've soreted out my problem
@R. Bemrose: :)

Comment: Can the values can exceed 999,999? If so, after dividing by 1000 you'll want to apply modulus 1000.

Answer (score 1):

as long as 193000 is an int, you can just divide it by 1000:

```
x = 193000.1
y = int(x)/1000
```

there's no filter already in Django, but you could add one yourself: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags